# Unable to import iTunes library after format

Tags: windows-8, itunes, itunes-11

I followed the steps in this article in apple's site to backup my iTunes library before a format: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1751?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

I use windows 8, with the latest iTunes, 11.0.5.5.

When I try to import the library, it loads and it's empty. (Or I think that's what it is, since when it loads, there is no change in the library).  The .itl file is about 700 kb, so I guess it is not empty. What could be wrong?

Comment: The article talks about moving your library to an external device not creating a .itl file.  Everything you purchase through iTunes can be simply downloaded again.

Comment: I have all the music in my external harddrive. If it loads the .itl correctly, it should save me from the trouble of adding all the music, folder by folder into the library. And other problems, such as copying all the apps from ipod to the computer.

Comment: If you place the files in their normal location that iTunes expects them at.  ITunes should simply automatically import them.

Comment: The files are at their normal location. (In an external drive, with drive letter fixed to X)

Comment: The default location for a iTunes library is the system drive though.  So the files are located within the `../iTunes/Music` directory?

Comment: There are some that are located within that folder (CD imports, recent purchases). The others are in the external drive. But it sees none of them.

Comment: Have you tried to simply move the files to that folder?

Comment: It didn't work.